# Xampp MYSQL não funciona

Tags: mysql, xampp

Esta acontecendo o seguinte erro com meu mysql.

> ```
> MySQL Service detected with wrong path
> Change XAMPP MySQL and Control Panel settings or
> Uninstall/disable the other service manually first
> Found Path: "C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.0\bin\mysqld-nt" --defaults-file="C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.0\my.ini" MySQL
> Expected Path: c:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe --defaults-file=c:\xampp\mysql\bin\my.ini mysql
> ```

Já verifiquei e não existe essa pasta dentro de Arquivos de programa e mesmo assim o xampp está direcionando para ela.

Answer (score 0):

Verifique o arquivo my.ini. Onde está apontando os caminhos

```
basedir="F:/mysql/"
datadir="F:/mysql/Data/"
```

Boa sorte

Comment: estavam todos como mysql/data.
alterei para apenas mysql/ e não funcionou

Comment: Provavelmente você tem outro serviço mysql apontando neste outro diretório:
 "C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.0\bin\mysqld-nt" --defaults-file="C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.0\my.ini" MySQL

Comment: Se tiver vc pode remover o serviço pelo cmd => sc delete nomedoservico

Comment: Eu tenho instalado outro serviço de MYSQL que é um ERP. Por isso não posso excluir.

Comment: Então você pode criar o serviço mysql_alguma_coisa e apontar para o my.ini correto, com isso o serviço vai funcionar. Segue o modelo de create service

C:\mysql\bin\mysqld --install MySQL_ALGUMA_COISA --defaults-file=C:\mysql\my.ini

Lembre-se de mudar a porta do seu mysql no arquivo my.ini para não ocorrer conflito com o seu erp.

Espero ter ajudado, abraços